# Hide Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba, hide, show

I am trying to hide different columns that are not next to each other.

I have a the below code but this allows me to only hide a range, eg in this case columns `H:K`. If I want to hide additional columns, say I want to hide `H:K` but also `S:T`, `X:Y` and column `Z:Z` - how do I get the below code to work for non-adjacent columns?

```
Option Explicit

'---------->>
Public Sub ToggleColumns()
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim obj As Variant
    Dim BTN As Button
    Dim iLen As Long
    Const myColumns As String = "H:K"               '<<===== Change
    Const sFees As String = "Fees"                       '<<===== Change
    Const sHidden As String = " Hidden"
    Const sVisible As String = " Visible"

    Set SH = ActiveSheet
    Set BTN = SH.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    Set Rng = SH.Columns(myColumns)
    With Rng.EntireColumn
        .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        If .Hidden Then
        iLen = Len(sHidden) + Len(sFees)
            BTN.Characters.Text = sFees & " Hidden"
            With BTN.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=iLen).Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Size = 10
                .ColorIndex = 3  '\\ RED
            End With
        Else
        iLen = Len(sVisible) + Len(sFees)
        BTN.Characters.Text = sFees & " Visible"
            With BTN.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=iLen).Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Size = 10
                .ColorIndex = 4  '\\ GREEN
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Const myColumns As String = "H:K,S:T,X:Y,Z:Z"` ?

Comment: @CLR I think that you are right.

Comment: @CLR `Columns(myColumns)` will fail as it does not support discontinued column addresses, while `Range()` does. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Const myColumns As String = "H:K"
```

with

```
Const myColumns As String = "H:K,S:T,X:Y,Z:Z"
```

and

```
Set Rng = SH.Columns(myColumns)
```

with

```
Set Rng = SH.Range(myColumns)
```

because `Columns()` does not support addresses with discontinued columns.